# tcomb-form-native remove underline field on android

Tags: android, forms, react-native, styles, tcomb-form-native

I am Using

tcomb-form-native v0.6.16
react-native v0.55.4
There is underline on the field on android

[image]

Since underlineColorAndroid isnt supported on this version.
How to remove The underline? Any idea?

Comment: Can you check your `lib/components` to have this [`prop`](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/blob/c7a9b257b98a4028f16deff96d7efd32a507fb87/lib/components.js#L270)

Comment: yes, its there, same as the file